# How to manage time properly mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database, servlets, timestamp

I have already a table with three time fields. One to register the hour when the user start working, when stop working and the difference. Now I want to add the day of the week(Mon-Sun) and the date. How can I properly do that, saying that then I will want to grab the hours that the user worked in the past 7 days, lets say.
I've read that timestamp give all the information but I don't know whether I can separate days from date?

```
**table name = date_time
date_time_id = auto increment
user_id = var
time_in = time
time_out = time
time_dif = time**
```

ps: I am using java(servlets) and mysql.

Thanks guys

Comment: Please post your table structure so far.

Answer (score 0):

when I start getting really silly with yime in MySql, I use unix time. MySql has built in functions for unix time conversion, too. FROM_UNIXTIME() is one of them. [Here's url of a reference page I use](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

I've been burned by MySql time (probably more by my own confusion) a few times, so I prefer unix time and then I can manually figure things out by factoring seconds into minutes *60 and hours *60*60 and days *24*60*60.

Comment: Thanks, but I really would like to know how timestamp works and whether is possible or not to use the way I want.

Comment: I recall the real problem is that MySql is limited to 2 timestamp columns (as far as built in behavior). I was writing a credit card processing application and also needed 3 timestamps. I set up a test database and played with all the different timestamp fields. Ultimately, I only use and trust the time entry created automagical MySql feature. Otherwise, it's all unix time for things like modified time or time counting. :P

Comment: So do you think it is better use another field in the table to register the day, month and year separately of the TIME field. Cause I was reading some explanations and it seems very trick to calculate the difference between two timestamp to get a formatted time. What do you reckon?

Comment: I wouldn't split that out. If it is all on the same server, unix time will be reliable. I have never had a time bug get me using unix time. Other times, yes. If this were my project, I'd have time_in be a timestamp data type and have it autopopulate upon creation with not allowed to be NULL. Then add time stamps into the time_out column. I seriously wouldn't bother with a third column.

Actually, my second column would be time worked... take the timestamp in, convert to unix time, take now in unix time then make the 2nd time column # of seconds worked.

Comment: I tried something here and it seems it is working. I can let my two columns as TIME and a third one which will register a timestamp. With those I can grab easily the difference between the two time(what I want). And register the day when the user timeout on the timestamp field

Answer (score 0):

Change your column types to TIMESTAMP instead of TIME.  A timestamp includes both a date and a time.

Comment: Thank, I am aware of that. However, what I want to know is how can I grab only the day or the month for instance.

Comment: You can use [EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) for that.  But if you want to check whether a date is within the past week, it's probably better to use [SUBDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subdate) to subtract 7 days from [CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp), and compare the stored timestamp against that.

Comment: ok thanks again. Just one thing. I've heard if I want the difference between two timestamp; Eg: 18:35:47, 18:32:45 the result is 302 and not 03:02. So that is my concern.

Comment: A time value like 3:02 represents a specific time of day, not a time interval.  I don't think there is an SQL type for a time interval, so I don't know what the return type would be when subtracting two timestamp values.  You might want to call [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) on both values and subtract the resulting integers; that'll give you the number of seconds between them.

Comment: One silly question. How can I calculate the difference between two columns of the same table. Thanks

Comment: That's what I just explained.  `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_out) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_in)` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You should hav column `datetime` type So you can easily get days month week whatever required.

Here all functions listed you can use as desired with `datetime` field:

[Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day)

Answer (score 0):

Use org.joda Datetime java library. Its very easy and you can do all the calculations using timestamp.